# grep command or awk to get particular data

Tags: awk, grep

i have a large text file

```
https://www.google.com/
https://www.google.com/hello?url=xxxxxx
https://www.google.com/admin?x=y&file=zzz
https://www.google.com/abc.png
https://www.google.com//abc.png
https://www.google.com/abc.svg
https://www.google.com/abc.jpg
https://www.google.com/admin?x=aaa&file=yyyy
https://www.google.com/hello?
```

all i want is urls with paramaters but same parameters shouldn't be their with different value

```
https://www.google.com/hello?url=xxxxxx
https://www.google.com/admin?x=y&file=zzz
```

i want this result

Answer (score 0):

You can use an associative array in `awk` to check whether you have seen the URI before, and so just print the first instance:

```
$ cat bar.txt
https://www.google.com/
https://www.google.com/hello?url=xxxxxx
https://www.google.com/admin?x=y&file=zzz
https://www.google.com/abc.png
https://www.google.com//abc.png
https://www.google.com/abc.svg
https://www.google.com/abc.jpg
https://www.google.com/admin?x=aaa&file=yyyy
https://www.google.com/hello?
$ awk -F? '$2 != "" && !already_seen[$1]++' bar.txt
https://www.google.com/hello?url=xxxxxx
https://www.google.com/admin?x=y&file=zzz
```